# Click handler, in react, doesn't return latest change in state when it executes a 2nd time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This takes place in a functional component:

```js
import {useEffect} from 'react';
let [clickedOnPiece, setClickedOnPiece] = useState(false);
let [testRender, setTestRender] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  testRenderFunction();
}, [])

function testRenderFunction() {
  let el = <div onClick={onClickHandler}>Click me</div>;
  setTestRender(el);
}

function onClickHandler() {
  if (clickedOnPiece) {
    console.log("already clicked")
    return
  }
  console.log(clickedOnPiece); //returns false the 1st & 2nd time.
  setClickedOnPiece("clicked");
}

return (
  <>
    {testRender}
  </>
)
```

When I click on `div` for the first time, I wait until `setClickedOnPiece("clicked")` successfully updates `clickedOnPiece` to `"clicked"`. (I check this with [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en)).

When I click `div` the 2nd time, it doesn't log the new change in state. It still logs `clickedOnPiece` as `false`. Why is this?

---

Comment: It's working properly. You can see it here https://codesandbox.io/s/issue1-gd9y2

Comment: Thanks @jonybekov I was actually simplifying my original problem too much. If you have a look at my question now, I've updated it to show the way in which I insert the div, which I believe causes the problem. If you were able to have a look at this that'd be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onClickHandler` references the old, previous variable, `clickedOnPiece`. I believe this is because `onClickHandler` is not defined in the `return` statement part of the functional component which would have allowed it a new `onClickHandler` body to be created each time. Instead, we have the old `onClickHandler` continually referencing the old `clickedOnPiece`.

This problem is known as 'stale closures' - a concept I found discussed well at the bottom of this [article](https://leewarrick.com/blog/react-use-effect-explained/)

Answer (score 0):

Okey this problem is because useState is asyncronus. u can read more about this [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately).

I think the solution is add useEffect like this.

```
useEffect( () => {
  console.log(clickOnPiece);
 }
, [clickOnPiece])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle the state, you could do something like this:

```
let [clickedOnPiece, setClickedOnPiece] = useState(false);

const onClickHandler = () => {
  // set the value of clickedOnPiece to the opposite of what it was
  // i.e. if it was 'true', set it to 'false'.
  setClickedOnPiece(!clickedOnPiece);
  console.log(clickedOnPiece);
}

// call the onClickHandler on click
<div onClick={()=>onClickHandler()}>Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are toggling

```
let [clickedOnPiece, setClickedOnPiece] = useState(false);

const onClickHandler = () => {
  console.log(clickedOnPiece);
  setClickedOnPiece(!clickedOnPiece);
}

console.log(clickedOnPiece);

<div onClick={onClickHandler}>Click me</div>
```

> After setting state, don't console immediately because state is an asynchronous.